# How to hide the progress bar when images loaded in grid view using glide

Tags: android, gridview, android-gallery, android-glide

I am a new android developer. I am making a grid view which contains a list of pictures. I'm using glide to load the images in image view, but the problem is that the progress bar did not disappear when the images loaded successfully. Here is my code:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;


RotateLoading rotateLoading;
int count;

public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
mContext = c;}

public int getCount() {
return mThumbIds.length;

}

@Override
public String getItem(int position) {
return mThumbIds[position];
}


public long getItemId(int position) {
return 0;
} 

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
ImageView imageView;

if (convertView == null) {
    convertView=        LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.image_gallery,parent,false);
    imageView=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(380,480));
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);

    rotateLoading=  (RotateLoading)convertView.findViewById(R.id.rotateloading);


} else {
    imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    **rotateLoading=  (RotateLoading)convertView.findViewById(R.id.rotateloading);**
}
String url = null;
url=getItem(position);

**rotateLoading.start();**
Glide.with(mContext)
        .load(url)
        .thumbnail(0.5f)
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
        .placeholder(android.R.drawable.progress_indeterminate_horizontal)
        .centerCrop()
        .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
            @Override
            public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                rotateLoading.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                rotateLoading.stop();
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {

                rotateLoading.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                rotateLoading.stop();

                return false;
            }
        })
        .crossFade()
        .into(imageView);
return convertView;
}

// Keep all Images in array
public String[] mThumbIds = {
    "http://idealphotography.biz/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Wide-wallpaper-nature-480x800-In-Wallpaper-HD-1366x768-with-wallpaper-nature-480x800-Download-HD-Wallpaper.jpg",
    "http://greenywallpapers.com/wallpapers/10/275050-nature-wallpapers-720x1280.jpg",
    "https://idealphotography.biz/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Best-wallpaper-nature-480x800-For-Wallpapers-Image-with-wallpaper-nature-480x800-Download-HD-Wallpaper.jpg",
    "https://idealphotography.biz/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Best-wallpaper-nature-480x800-In-Windows-Wallpaper-Themes-with-wallpaper-nature-480x800-Download-HD-Wallpaper.jpg",
    "https://idealphotography.biz/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Highres-wallpaper-nature-480x800-About-Windows-7-Wallpaper-with-wallpaper-nature-480x800-Download-HD-Wallpaper.jpg",
    "http://freewallpaper-background.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/M-3.jpg",
    "http://naturewallpaperfree.com/mobile/sky/nature-wallpaper-480x800-127-96fbd452.jpg",

};

}
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageView
android:layout_width="380dp"
android:layout_height="380dp"
android:id="@+id/imageView2"
/>
<com.victor.loading.rotate.RotateLoading
android:id="@+id/rotateloading"
android:layout_width="80dp"
android:layout_height="80dp"
app:loading_width="5dp"
app:loading_color="#ffffff"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:visibility="visible"/>       
</RelativeLayout>
```

I also used the default progress bar but it also did not disappear.

Comment: Change your "RotateLoading" visibility to visible in xml -- android:visibility="visible"

Comment: Sir Thanks for response. i just update my question check the code i bold the code which i added.
rotateprogress bar remain visible when images loaded,

Comment: please solve my issue, i shall be very thankful to you.

Comment: I created a library to achieve exactly this behaviour (among others). Try to use my [PowerfulImageView](https://github.com/stefanosiano/PowerfulImageView) instead of normal imageview.  
Simply use   
`<com.stefanosiano.powerfulimageview.PowerfulImageView  
    ...  
    app:piv_progress_mode="circular" />`  
Or through java:  
to show the progress  
`powerfulImageView.changeProgressMode(PivProgressMode.CIRCULAR);`  
or to hide  
`powerfulImageView.changeProgressMode(PivProgressMode.NONE);`
  
Let me know if everything is fine :)

Comment: ok i will check

Comment: can we add custom progressbar instead of this?